# Webwindow is not valid. It was closed by user or the process was terminated

Tags: matlab, simulink

Every time I finish testing some Simulink blocks from Design Verifier, I save and quit the current Simulink view, open a new one and get greeted by this annoying error that forces me to quit and restart Matlab.

```
Webwindow is not valid. It was closed by user or the process was terminated.
```

Is there any way to fix or prevent it?